# Refresh materlized view with crontab

Tags: linux, postgresql, cron, refresh

so first of and a quick explination, i've tried to search and look up, some say its not posseble and some say it works.

a crontab job, i did find something with a cronjob, but it didnt work since that was for oracle.

i use postgres and debian, i tried to do somthing in the style of "*/5 * * * * su postgres -d psql -d your_database -c "REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW CONCURRENTLY 
vm_available_items"

but this did not work. It first needs to be su postgres and then psql, and then "data base" and than the refersh command.

Im really new and i hope i don't cause to much troupple asking this question, i have been trying to ether find a trigger for this, or a refresh (mostly the refresh option)

Answer (score 0):

You can set a `crontab` specifically for the `postgres` user - you simply need to run `crontab -e` as user postgres: ie. `su postgres crontab -e`.

Then just add the entry to run your `psql` command to refresh the materialized view:

```
 */5 * * * * psql -d your_database -c "REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW CONCURRENTLY vm_available_items"
```